# Using CloneFunctionInto() by llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-3.0

I need to clone a function into another function by CloneFunctionInto in an LLVM function pass, to keep the original control flow graph from any change I may make in the first.

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Cloning_8h_source.html

```
void CloneFunctionInto(Function *NewFunc, const Function *OldFunc, ValueToValueMapTy &VMap, bool ModuleLevelChanges, SmallVectorImpl<ReturnInst*> &Returns, const char *NameSuffix = "", ClonedCodeInfo *CodeInfo = 0, ValueMapTypeRemapper *TypeMapper = 0);
```

Could anyone help me with it, because I have some missing parts like `ClonedCodeInfo` and `ValueMapTypeRemapper`?

If you please give me an example to get better understanding

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pulling from [doxygen](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/structllvm_1_1ClonedCodeInfo.html), the `ClonedCodeInfo` class can be used to get information back about the function that you just cloned, namely whether or not the function contains calls or dynamic alloca instructions.

Again the [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ValueMapTypeRemapper.html) for `ValueMapTypeRemapper` tells us it is an abstract base class that requires any subclass implement its `remapType()` method.  As the name implies, this can be used to replace certain types in your function with other types.

Here's some sample code:

```
class MessageUpdater: public ValueMapTypeRemapper
{
public:
    Type *remapType(Type *SrcTy)
    {
        std::map<Type *, Type *>::iterator i, e;
        for (i = foo.begin(), e = foo.end(); i != e; ++i) {
            if (SrcTy == i->first) {
                return i->second;
            }
        }

        assert(0 && "Type not found in map!");
        return 0;
    }
    std::map<Type *, Type *> foo;
};
```

And you can call it like this:

```
MessageUpdater foobar;

foobar.foo.insert(std::make_pair(fromStruct, toStruct));
foobar.foo.insert(std::make_pair(fromStructPtr, toStructPtr));
foobar.foo.insert(std::make_pair(fromStructPtrPtr, toStructPtrPtr));

for (inst_iterator I = inst_begin(f), E = inst_end(f); I != E; ++I) {
    foobar.foo.insert(std::make_pair(I->getType(), I->getType()));
}

std::map<Type *, Type *>::iterator i, e;
for (i = foobar.foo.begin(), e = foobar.foo.end(); i != e; ++i) {
    errs() << *i->first << " maps to " << *i->second << "\n";
}

CloneFunctionInto(newFun, f, vmap, false, Returns, "", 0, &foobar);
```

You'll notice that you aren't required to pass a `ClonedCodeInfo` object into this function and so I simply pass in 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
here is a small example:
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h"
#include "llvm/AsmParser/Parser.h"
//#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
//#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/MCJIT.h"
//#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"
//#include "llvm/IR/TypeBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/Utils/Cloning.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace llvm;
using namespace std;
 

int main(){
    static LLVMContext TheContext;
    char irFile1[] = "wait.ll";
    //LLVMContext &Context1 = getGlobalContext();
    SMDiagnostic Err1;
    std::unique_ptr<Module> Mod1= parseIRFile(irFile1, Err1, TheContext);
    for(auto iter = Mod1->begin() ; iter != Mod1->end(); iter++){
        string name((*iter).getName());
        std::cout << name <<std::endl;
        ;;
    }
    // auto &functionList = Mod1->getFunctionList();
    // for(auto tFun : functionList){
        
    //     // if(tFun->getName() != "main"){
    //     //     funVec.emplace_back(tFun);
    //     // }else{
    //     //     printf("%s\n" , tFun->getName());
    //     // }
        
    // }

//     char irFile2[] = "insert.ll";
//    // LLVMContext &Context2 = getGlobalContext();
//     SMDiagnostic Err2;
//     std::unique_ptr<Module> Mod2= parseIRFile(irFile2, Err2, TheContext);
    Module *relaseMod1 = Mod1.release();
    SMDiagnostic error;
    StringRef ImplAssembly = R"(
        define dso_local void @_Z3fooPiS_(i32* %0, i32* %1) #0 {
  %3 = alloca i32*, align 8
  %4 = alloca i32*, align 8
  store i32* %0, i32** %3, align 8
  store i32* %1, i32** %4, align 8
  %5 = load i32*, i32** %3, align 8
  store i32 1, i32* %5, align 4
  %6 = load i32*, i32** %4, align 8
  store i32 1, i32* %6, align 4
  ret void
}
    )";
    auto InjectedModule = parseAssemblyString(ImplAssembly, error, relaseMod1->getContext());
    auto* ImplFunction = InjectedModule->getFunction("_Z3fooPiS_");
    // std::vector<string> funVec;
    // for(auto iter = Mod2->begin() ; iter != Mod2->end(); iter++){
       
    //     string name((*iter).getName());
        
    //     ;;
    //     if(name != "main")
    //     {
    //         funVec.emplace_back(name);
    //         std::cout << name <<std::endl;
    //     }
        
    // }
    // std::vector<llvm::Function*> funVec;
    // for(auto tFun : Mod2->functions ()){
    //     if(tFun->getName() != "main"){
    //         funVec.emplace_back(tFun);
    //     }else{
    //         printf("%s\n" , tFun->getName());
    //     }
        
    // }

    //auto InjectedModule = parseAssemblyString(ImplAssembly, error, M.getContext());
    
    //llvm::Function* ImplFunction = Mod2->getFunction(funVec[0]);
    //ImplFunction->print(std::cout);
    llvm::Function* DeclFunction = Function::Create(ImplFunction->getFunctionType(), ImplFunction->getLinkage(), "_Z3fo111oPiS_", relaseMod1);
    llvm::ValueToValueMapTy VMap;
    //VMap[ImplFunction] = DeclFunction;
    Function::arg_iterator DestI = DeclFunction->arg_begin();
    for (Function::const_arg_iterator J = ImplFunction->arg_begin(); J != ImplFunction->arg_end();
         ++J) {
      DeclFunction->setName(J->getName());
      VMap[J] = DestI++;
    }
    //VMap[&*ImplFunction->arg_begin()] = &*DeclFunction->arg_begin();
    SmallVector<ReturnInst*, 8> Returns;
    CloneFunctionInto(DeclFunction, ImplFunction, VMap, llvm::CloneFunctionChangeType::DifferentModule, Returns);
    //relaseMod1->dump();
    relaseMod1->print(llvm::errs(), nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).